# Pivot dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Current df:

| Week | Sales | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 56 |
| 2 | 42 | 57 |
| 3 | 20 | 6 |

I am trying to get the following structure:

| Week | Parameter | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales | 34 |
| 1 | Revenue | 56 |
| 2 | Sales | 42 |
| 2 | Revenue | 57 |
| 3 | Sales | 20 |
| 3 | Revenue | 6 |

I have tried the following but I 'values' only accepts one column.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df1, values = 'Sales', index=['Week','Revenue'], columns = 'Week').reset_index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `melt`, the inverse operation of pivot.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt

```py
df1.melt(id_vars=["Week"], var_name="Parameter", value_name="Total")
```

Note that `stack` is also doing a similar operation (and unstack is similar to `pivot`). But `stack/unstack` solely rely on (multi)index to understand what you wish to do, while melt/pivot are more configurable

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.set_index('Week').stack().reset_index()
 .set_axis(['Week', 'Parameter', 'Total'], axis=1))
```

---

Alternatively,

```
(df.set_index('Week').stack().rename('Total').to_frame()
 .reset_index(names=['Week', 'Parameter']))
```

---

Output:

```
   Week Parameter  Total
0     1     Sales     34
1     1   Revenue     56
2     2     Sales     42
3     2   Revenue     57
4     3     Sales     20
5     3   Revenue      6
```